# scaffolding Login and Logout results in redirection to logout page when logging in

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages, identity, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I created a new razor pages project with Individual Accounts.
I scaffolded Login and Logout pages.
I ran it, I registered a new user, then I logged out and again logged in.
I expected to be directed to homepage after login but I was redirected to logout page.
I saw that when logging out, ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FLogout  is being concatenated to the login page, and that causes the redirection to the logout immediately after the login.

Who concatenates this ReturnUrl and why?